# AngularJS routing with ASP.Net MVC produces weird URLs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using AngularJS routing in my ASP.Net MVC web application and it is working fine. However it produces weird URLs in the address bar as I navigate through angular routing. The routin code I have used is given below:

Routing code -

```
var app = angular.module("webApp",['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(
        "/",{
            templateUrl: "home/dashboard",
            controller: "webCtrl"
        })
        .when(
            "/page1",{
                templateUrl: "home/contact",
                controller: "page1Ctrl"
        });
});
```

Navigation-

```
<body ng-app="webApp">
    <a href="#/">Home</a>
    <a href="#!page1">Page1</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

For home page it produces URL `http://localhost:58193/#!/` and for `page1` it produces `http://localhost:58193/#!/page1`. When I click on the `Home` link again it produces `http://localhost:58193/#!/#%2F` which is totally different from the first one. Please let me know how to display proper URLs.

Comment: why you given <a href="#!page1">Page1</a>. Just change href="#/page1"

Answer (score 0):

Enable html5mode. This can solve your problem.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location
 https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```